# what do we call people who watch football

Tags: nouns

In everyday talks, I encountered the following problem. I have always used the word "fans" to refer to those who watch football. However, when I tried to just refer to the people and not how they feel about it, I didn't know what to say. Therefore, here is my question:

What do we call people who watch football: audiences / viewers / watchers / spectators?

Comment: Do you mean specifically people who watch TV? Then _viewers_ would be a good fit. _Spectators_ would be more suitable for people who go to matches.

Comment: You can't mean football specifically. Do you mean only sports?  (None of the words you suggest apply only to sports . . .) But if it's not a single word you want, then "football" or "sports" could easily modify what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

"Spectators" is great for those who watch sports.